# Minecraft Bedrock Server Console log chat and command executions

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I am trying to start an SMP with my friends, but I discovered that logs for commands executed by admins and chat history don't show on the console. I need to be able to see the command logs so that I can make sure admins don't cheat. I also want to be able to talk to the players on the server through the console if I can't play Minecraft. I searched on the web but couldn't find anything that may help me. I was forced to use Java and Geyser as a temporary solution, but it is laggy for bedrock players and takes up a lot of ram for my server.

In summary: Is there any way to see the logs for chat and commands executed by admins on the console of the bedrock server?

Update: I researched deeper on how to do this and still didn't find anything helpful. I found a third-party server software that might be able to do what I'm trying to do on the console, but I want to see if there is still a way to see the logs on the official bedrock server software. **Changing the question: Is there at least a file in the directory of a Bedrock server that contains the logs of the chat and execution of commands by admins in the directory of the Bedrock server?**